# Forcing orgmode page breaks on Git

Tags: org-mode, github

When I create org documents I make sure that I have this setting in my init.el file:

```
'(org-export-preserve-breaks t)
```

One can also use `#+OPTIONS: \n:t`  on a file-per-file basis to force `org` to preserve all line breaks when exporting. This works fine when I export an org file using `C-c C-e`. However, if I upload the org file to Git, it does not display with the line breaks. For example:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 2
Line 4
```

Displays as

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 2 Line 4
```

I have tried adding \\ at the end of each line, but when uploaded to Git, it appears as

```
Line\1\Line\2\Line 2\Line 4
```

I would like it simply to appear as

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 2
Line 4
```

Comment: I am running Emacs on Ubuntu. By "upload" I mean simply `git add . && git commit -m 'update' && git push`. I am speaking of the display of the files in Git.

Comment: What  Git repo are you doing the `git push` against? FWIW, everything I've tried so far (in my imperfect understanding of what you are doing exactly) has not shown any problems, with or without the settings.

Comment: Please check this link below, to a test file I have just created.

Comment: https://github.com/revrari/test/blob/main/test.org

Comment: The public file on Git appears differently than it does on my PC.

Comment: https://github.com/revrari/test/blob/main/Screenshot%20from%202023-01-09%2020-13-50.png

Comment: That's because *Github* converts Org mode files to "Github-flavored markdown" or some such. It has nothing to do with Org and nothing to do with Git. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017206/how-can-i-make-emacs-org-docs-more-beautiful-in-github-repository for some discussion and problems with that.

Comment: It's a real problem for me now as I am going to have to re-edit all my shared public files. Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: Not really: I'd suggest you familiarize yourself with https://github.com/github/markup and since, as mentioned on that page,  Org mode files are processed through [org-ruby](https://github.com/wallyqs/org-ruby), you should familiarize yourself with that. But it seems that there is a lot of Org mode features that that does not cover. Feel free to complain to Github about this, although I suspect they won't do much about it. Note BTW: `Github != Git`.

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/43837